# Google Drive API integration is not working with live URL

Tags: c#, integration, flysystem-google-drive

i am trying to upload documents using google Drive API integration, working fine in case of localhost but not working on live domain.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"" + folderPathForCredentials, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
    // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.

    String FolderPath = @"" + folderPathForToken;
    String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "token.json");

    stream.Dispose();
    stream.Close();

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientID,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;
}

//create Drive API service.
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = applicationName,
});
return service;
```

And this is the code to Upload on Google Drive.

```
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        request = _service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.Upload();
        stream.Dispose();
        stream.Close();
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        //return request.ResponseBody;
        return Json(new JsonData { IsSuccess = true, Message = "Uploaded Successfully", Data = null });
    }
}
```

Let me help in configuring the drive with live domain.

Comment: Sorry but "not working" is not an error message or problem statement we can help with. It gives us no idea of what kind of specific issue you are encountering, and we cannot guess. It's like saying to a mechanic "my car is not working, please fix it" but without letting them test the car. Please provide some more detailed information. If you haven't yet tried to do some proper debugging, now would be the time to try. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance on how to ask a question to give the best chance of people being able to answer it accurately. Thanks.

Comment: ADyson i cannot debugg with live URL. Also i have no server rights. But i can debug with live data but issue is again the url will be localhost, not live.

Comment: In that case you need to add some logging (e.g. of exceptions, responses to API requests, and any other relevant data) into the code so it saves data to the disk on the server, and you can inspect it to see what's happening. Like I said, there is absolutely nothing we or anyone else can do to help you based on the minimal description provided.